# How to create editable data in WPF DataGrid using EF?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid

I'm using EF6 Code First and WPF DataGrid.
Say, I have two columns, T1 and T2, with one-to-one relationship:

```
-- Create tables.
-- This is the parent table.
create table dbo.T1
(
    id int primary key,
    addr varchar(100) not null
);
-- This is the child table.
create table dbo.T2
(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);

-- Set primary "id" column of T2 as foreign key.  
alter table dbo.T2
    add constraint T1_pk
    foreign key (id) references dbo.T1(id);

-- Insert some sample values
insert into dbo.T1 values (1, 'addr1'), (2, 'addr2'), (3, 'addr3');
insert into dbo.T2 values (1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2');
```

I want 1) to show all columns in DataGrid from T2 child table and some columns from parent T1 table, as the following SQL expresses, and 2) make this data editable:

```
select T1.id, T1.addr, T2.name
from dbo.T1 left join dbo.T2 on T1.id = T2.id;
```

I solved the first part of my problem with the following:

```
var query = from r1 in db.T1 
            join r2 in db.T2 on r1.id equals r2.id into gj
            from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                r1.id,
                r1.addr,
                name = (x == null ? string.Empty : x.name)
            };
query.Load();
dg.ItemsSource = null;
dg.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

But this makes data read-only. So, how I can achieve the "editability" of data? The data, returned by query, should somehow be related to underlying entities, but can't figure it out. Please, help me to solve this problem! Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to pack query result into special join class 
like this

```
var query = from r1 in db.T1
            join r2 in db.T2 on r1.ID equals r2.ID into gj
            from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {T1 = r1, T2 = x};

 dg.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<JoinT1T2Class>(query.ToList().Select(n=>new JoinT1T2Class(n.T1,n.T2)));
//Here is editable DataSource; 


public class JoinT1T2Class
{
    private T1 _T1;
    private T2 _T2;

    public JoinT1T2Class(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        this._T1 = t1;
        this._T2 = t2;
    }

    public int ID { get { return _T1.ID; } }

    public string Addr { get { return _T1!=null?_T1.Addr:string.Empty; } set { if (_T1!=null)_T1.Addr = value; } }
    public string Name { get { return _T2!=null?_T2.Name:string.Empty; } set { if(_T2!=null)_T2.Name = value; } }
}
```

where T1 and T2 are your Entity classes.

```
public class T1
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("addr")]
    public string Addr { get; set; }
}

public class T2
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
     [Column("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

To be able to store your changes into DataBase you have save the reference on your DataContext in private variable and dispose it on window closed;

To save any changes you have to call db.SaveChanges();

Use CollectionChanged event handler if you need to process addition or removing rows

```
ObservableCollection<JoinT1T2Class> dataSource = new ObservableCollection<JoinT1T2Class>(query.ToList().Select(n=>new JoinT1T2Class(n.T1,n.T2)));
dataSource.CollectionChanged += dataSource_CollectionChanged;

void dataSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:                   
                 // to access added items use  e.NewItems
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:                    
                 // to access deleted items use e.OldItems
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. But it raises another question: how to create and save new entity of T2, in case if there's no such record in database (in other words, all columns related to T2 are empty)?
There are empty cells which relate to T2. By entering values into these cells, it is assumed that I create new T2 entity. So, how to create and save it?

Comment: add method 
public T2 CreateNewT2()
      {
          _T2 = new T2(){ID=_T1.ID};
          return _T2
      }
 to JoinT1T2Class

and try this

   db.T2.Add(CurrentJoinClassItem.CreateNewT2());
   db.T2.SaveChanges();

  but it needs that your T2.ID is uniq primary key but not autogenerated

Comment: I don't understand why you need 2 tables fo this. May be there is the way to pack Name and adress in one table together. It would be easier and more stable

Comment: Thanks for answer! Gonna try it a bit later. As for creating one single table, there's one catch - I have ~300 columns, and it wouldn't be wise to create one table with 300 columns, because of, say, page overflow (page would be > 8K). That's why I split this table into several with one-to-one relationship.

Comment: OK. I have finally figured it out that I need to create one single entity and map appropriate properties to columns.  
 In my case, I create some entity called "Test" with all properties from T1 and T2. Then I map them to those tables in database.

Comment: But in reality I have 300 columns, and it means that I need to create entity with 300 properties and map them to database tables thru configuration.  
It means that every selection of, say, 15 columns will initialize all remained 285 properties. And there will be, say, 1000 such entities from database. Will the performance suffer from this?

Comment: Also, in this scenario EF issues INNER JOIN rather LEFT OUTER JOIN, which I actually need.